# What seven letter word am I?

Tags: rhyme, knowledge

> To few I am real, but to others I am fiction.
>
> My effect precedes a cause, but you feel my infix as a result of affliction.
>
> My very nature puts everything at stake,
>
> because I violate a rule you will never break.

I am a seven-letter word. What am I?

HINT 1:

> I begin with idiomatic perfection.

HINT 2:

> You don't want to end a sentence with my suffix.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE! If you want to get a badge you can take a [tour here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you stay :D

Comment: Now, are you using effect (def: cause (something) to happen; bring about or a change that is a result or consequence of an action or other cause.) or affect (def: have an effect on; make a difference to.)?

Comment: Effect -- with an 'e.'

Answer (score 2):

how about

> opinion?

because

> opinions are 'real' to some and 'fiction' to others

and

> you can feel 'pins and needles' due to afflictions (pin)

and

> one grammar rule is to never end a sentence with 'on'

still working on seeing if any of the other hints/clues fit.

Comment: Not it, but a good guess. Keep working on the other hint and clues.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be

> THOUGHT

As,

To few I am real, but to others I am fiction.

> few thoughts can be realized/ materialised, whereas many can remain as fiction/ imaginary

My effect precedes a cause, but you feel my infix as a result of affliction.

> Infix is - *though*

My very nature puts everything at stake,

> As, a thought is supposed to be the cause behind every action

because I violate a rule you will never break.

> As, thought is supposed to be originated in silence- which never breaks a rule - which requires to maintain silence.

I am a seven-letter word. What am I?

> THOUGHT has seven letters.

Answer (score 0):

i think it could be :

> DESTINY

As,

To few I am real, but to others I am fiction.

> Many think destiny exists but not everybody

My effect precedes a cause, but you feel my infix as a result of affliction.

> Many think every things happened to human is already written somewhere , and take this as a fatality when bad things happened

My very nature puts everything at stake,

> Those who believe in Destiny also think that everything happened in a
>  precise order,

because I violate a rule you will never break.

> Destiny always choose for everybody ,everything.It rule the life of
>  everybody and determine their future as it wants But humans can't interfere in others life  nor know or determine their own future just like
>  they want.

I am a seven-letter word. What am I?

> Destiny is a seven letters word

I begin with idiomatic perfection

> The beliefs in Destiny is inherent to a category of person who believe
>  in supernatural things a some kind of perfection of things

wiktionary defines it as:

> destiny (plural destinies)
>  
>  1. That to which any person or thing is destined; a predetermined
>      state; a condition predestined by the Divine or by human will
>
>      Synonyms: fate, lot
>  2. The fixed order of things; invincible necessity; an irresistible
>    power or agency conceived of as determining the future, whether in
>    general or of an individual. Synonym: fate